# python :- IndexError: list index out of range when converting list into dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, netsh

Idea is to get output of "netsh wlan show interfaces" into a dictionary , so that values can be fetched based on key.

Error observed is:

> IndexError: list index out of range

```
import subprocess
results = subprocess.check_output("netsh wlan show interfaces")
results = results.decode("ascii")
results = results.replace("\r","")
ls = results.split("\n")
ls = ls[3:]
dict = {}
temp = []

for i in ls:
    temp = i.split(":")
    m = temp[0].strip()
    dict[m] = temp[1].strip()

print(dict)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may not be a `":"` in every line of the command's output, so you should use an `if` statement to make sure it does before assuming there are more than one item in the list returned by `i.split(":")`:

```
for i in ls:
    temp = i.split(":", 1)
    if len(temp) > 1:
        m = temp[0].strip()
        dict[m] = temp[1].strip()
```

Comment: highly appreciate your help , your input helped me get the things right